# Updating plugin.xml file in an external supplied jar file

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have the following content in my plugin.xml that I receive from an external vendor. As you can see, I would be able to see two different views by the name **Risk Details** and **Ranking Details**.

I am interested in changing the text to a different one, say, **My Risk Details** and **My Ranking Details**.

Also, I would be receiving the same jar file ( which contains the plugin.xml ) as and when a bug fix is delivered by the external vendor.

What is the best way of dealing with such scenario?.

What I have on my mind:
Manually extract the content of the jar file, update the plugin.xml and finally zip it back and rename the zip file to jar file again, and add it to our build system. But this is quite tedious and error prone. In the event that I miss this manual update, things would revert back to the default settings.

```
   <extension point="org.eclipse.ui.views">
      <view
            name="Ghi"
            icon="icons/application_Ghi_16.png"
            class="com.abc.def.GhiHeaderView"
            id="com.abc.def.GhiHeaderView">
      </view>
      <view
            name="Risk Details"
            icon="icons/application_Ghi_16.png"
            class="com.abc.def.GhiRiskView"
            id="com.abc.def.GhiRiskView">
      </view>
      <view
            name="Ranking Details"
            icon="icons/application_Ghi_16.png"
            class="com.abc.def.GhiRankingView"
            id="com.abc.def.GhiRankingView">
      </view>
   </extension>
```

Request you to share some pointers on what can be done to improve this process.

Thanks,
Pavan.

Comment: Since this plugin.xml is not using the Eclipse NLS support there is no clever way to update it. Note that if the plugin jar is signed you can't change it at all as you will break the signing.

Comment: Why do you want to change the name in plugin.xml , you may be able to set name for your view programmatically.

Comment: @svasa There is an application the external vendor supports and this jar file is part of it. There is no customization that we have at the moment on top of this application. If you can help me with any such references that would be great.